# Regular expression for matching patterns [] or [][] explicitly.?

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am writing a parser for a scripting language that is used for benchmarking experiments. I am introducing a concept of 1-dimension and 2-dimension arrays in it and tried to write a regular expression in order to explicitly match **an occurrence** of `[]` or `[][]` in a statement and accordingly handle storage and retrieval of array values internally.

I have written a REGEX that matches

[[][]](https://regex101.com/r/EyNxAD/1), and

[[]](https://regex101.com/r/EyNxAD/2) explicitly, but

the issue is, in the second case my REGEX is dependent on matching a pattern for variable definition in any programming language before matching`[]`.

Could anyone suggest another way of writing REGEX for 2nd which is independent of matching a variable pattern before it and should only match a single occurrence of `[]` kind?

For Example.:

the 2nd REGEX **should not match** any substrings in a STRING:

**array1`[123]` `[345]`**

Instead, it should **only match**

**array2`[12]`**

I tried [[]](https://regex101.com/r/EyNxAD/3) but, it is partially correct as it also matches

**array[1]`[2]`**

**prefix[23423]`[23435]`** which I do not want it to.

Can someone help, How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!])\[\d+](?!\[)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cBACF2/2).

**Details**

- `(?<!])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `]` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\[` - a `[`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `]` - a `]` char
- `(?!\[)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `[` immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Very nice, and an excellent example of how one should explain a regex that is given in an answer.  I see far too many regex answers that say only _"Use this: <line-noise>"_

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
(?<!\])(\[\d+\])(?=[^[])
```

explanation

```
(?<!\]) - lookbehind for any character diferent from "[" (this also consumes the caracter so they won´t be on the match)

(\[\d+\]) - find digits surrounded by []

(?=[^[]) - lookahead for any character that isn't "[" (this won't be taken in the match)
```

[examples](https://regex101.com/r/c2JoGx/1)

<strike>Try this</strike>

```
(?<!\])(\[\d+\])(?>\s)
```

Comment: Yeah.!! it works well but then it is dependent on a white space after the matching the ```[]``` which I think should not be expected from the user. [The user might enter '=' or ':=' or ';' any other other character depending upon the definition rules of a statement in a programming language, options are endless.](https://regex101.com/r/EyNxAD/5) Is there a way we can make more independent and keep matcher limits to ```[]``` only?

Comment: If you don't _explain_ the regex it's just _<line-noise>_ — later visitors won't learn from it.

Answer (score -1):

Can try this one.

```
[\[|\]]
```

Match all inside the occurrences.

Comment: That will not solve the purpose, it will make the situation worse. please see [here](https://regex101.com/r/EyNxAD/4)

Comment: That's weird. I wrote a programm in C# and works for me.